# Как сделать xmlHttpRequest кроссбраузерным?

Tags: ajax, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Привет всем, делаю простой чат на чистом Javascript и столкнулся с одной проблемой:

А именно с кроссбраузерностью... При создании объекта xmlHttpRequest начинаются проблемы в новых браузерах Google Chrome и Mozilla Firefox (в других не тестировал). Сейчас глянул, как работает в IE8 - с объектом xmlHttpRequest все ОК, но есть много других проблем...

Вот код:

```
function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try{
        xmlHttp = new xmlHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e){
        var XmlHttpVersions = new Array("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        for (var i = 0; i < XmlHttpVersions.length && !xmlHttp; i++) {
            try{
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(XmlHttpVersions[i]);
            }
            catch (e){}
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp) {
        alert("Ошибка создания объекта xmlHttpRequest.");
    }else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}
```

В браузерах Google Chrome и Mozilla Firefox постоянно выскакивает **alert("Ошибка создания объекта xmlHttpRequest.");**

Как мне нужно изменить этот код, чтобы сделать его кроссбраузерным и заставить работать в современных браузерах?

Comment: @woland Можете преобразовать в ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум соблюдать регистр: new XMLHttpRequest().